# What does the underscore wrapping do in angular? I don't understand reference resolution

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am reading about the [inject method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject)

In this code, I use it, but I don't know why I am using it. Why am I using it?

```
describe('PhoneCat controllers', function() {

describe('PhoneListCtrl', function(){
  var scope, ctrl, $httpBackend;

  // Load our app module definition before each test.
  beforeEach(module('phonecatApp'));

  // The injector ignores leading and trailing underscores here (i.e. _$httpBackend_).
  // This allows us to inject a service but then attach it to a variable
  // with the same name as the service in order to avoid a name conflict.
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $httpBackend.expectGET('phones/phones.json').
        respond([{name: 'Nexus S'}, {name: 'Motorola DROID'}]);

    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('PhoneListCtrl', {$scope: scope});
  }));
```

#### **Resolving References (Underscore Wrapping)**

Often, we would like to inject a reference once, in a beforeEach() block and reuse this in multiple it() clauses. To be able to do this we must assign the reference to a variable that is declared in the scope of the describe() block. Since we would, most likely, want the variable to have the same name of the reference we have a problem, **since the parameter to the inject() function would hide the outer variable.**

**Question: What does the quote section in bold mean?**

To help with this, the injected parameters can, optionally, be enclosed with underscores. These are ignored by the injector when the reference name is resolved.

Comment: It means that if you do `$httpBackend = $httpBackend` (or even without that), it has no effect on the variable $httpBackend on the outer scope ( defined in describe('PhoneListCtrl')). Function argument variable declaration (in the inject in your case) is only local to that function. Well you do not have to do that, instead declare outer one as `httpBackend` and assign `$httpBackend` to it.

Comment: Oh I see so if I did $httpBackend = $httpBackend, it wouldn't affect the $httpBackend in the first line of the describe block/outer scope because both $httpBackend variables would refer to the one inside the inject argument right?

Answer (score 1):

It means you can't access `$httpBackend` declared in the scope of the describe() block if you didn't enclose parameters with underscores.

Assume we don't enclose parameters with underscores, it looks like:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($httpBackend, $rootScope, $controller) {
    $httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    $httpBackend.expectGET('phones/phones.json').
        respond([{name: 'Nexus S'}, {name: 'Motorola DROID'}]);

    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('PhoneListCtrl', {$scope: scope});
}));
```

As you see, in statement `$httpBackend = $httpBackend;`, `$httpBacken` is exactly the parameter `$httpBackend` of `function($httpBackend, $rootScope, $controller)`. However what you want to assign is `$httpBackend` declared in `var scope, ctrl, $httpBackend;`